# How set Long id new java.util.Date().getTime() to @GeneratedValue

Tags: java, hibernate

How set primary key Long id = new java.util.Date().getTime() to @GeneratedValue?

My piece of code:

```
private Long id;
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about you try with custom Generator, something like;

```
package x.y.z;
public class LongGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator { 

        @Override 
        public Serializable generate(final SessionImplementor sessionImplementor, final Object object) throws HibernateException { 
            return new java.util.Date().getTime(); 
        }
}
```

and:

```
    private Long id;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "x.y.z.LongGenerator")
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
```